# What can you call a low quality "best 10 everything" website?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Sometimes when you google something like "best camping stove" or "best coffee maker" (just examples) you can see low-quality websites that look very similar, full of amazon affiliate links. And if you know something about the topic (camping/coffee in my example) you quickly understand that the text is written by a freelancer/copywriter (probably not even a native speaker) who understands nothing about the products he/she writes about. What can I call such a website in 1-3 words?

Answer (score 5):

I think "[content farm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_farm)" is what you are looking for. The definition that [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20content%20farm) provides is

> a website that contains very large quantities of content, typically of low quality or aggregated from other sites, generated solely to ensure that it appears high on the list of results returned by a search engine.

Another option might be "[clickbait](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20clickbait)", but I think that tends to be associated more with news articles that have overly sensational or misleading headlines.

Comment: "Clickbait" is the link that gets you to a site like this, so strongly related, but not quite correct for describing the site.

Answer (score 1):

**spam site** or **spam blog** is what I would call it. Wikipedia has **splog** but I've never heard that.

> A spam blog, also known as an auto blog or the neologism splog, is a blog which the author uses to promote affiliated websites, to increase the search engine rankings of associated sites or to simply sell links/ads.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spam_blog